# Distribute quantities into buckets - Not evenly

Tags: c#, random, distribution

I've been searching around for a solution to this, but I think because of how I'm thinking about it, my search phrases might be a bit loaded in favor of topics that aren't completely relevant.

I have a number, say 950,000. This represents an inventory of [widgets] within an entire system. I have about 200 "buckets" that should each receive a portion of this inventory such that there are no widgets left over.

What I would like to happen is for each bucket to receive different amounts. I don't have any solid code to show right now, but here's some pesudo code to illustrate what I've been thinking:

```
//List<BucketObject> _buckets is a collection of "buckets", each of which has a "quantity" property for holding these numbers.

int _widgetCnt = 950000;
int _bucketCnt = _buckets.Count;     //LINQ
//To start, each bucket receives (_widgetCnt / _bucketCnt) or 4750.

for (int _b = 0; b< _bucketCnt - 1; i++)
{
     int _rndAmt = _rnd.Next(1, _buckets[i].Quantity/2); //Take SOME from this bucket...
     int _rndBucket = _rnd.Next(0,_bucketCnt - 1);    //Get a random bucket index from the List<BucketObject> collection.

     _buckets.ElementAt(_rndBucket).Quantity += _rndAmt;
     _buckets.ElementAt(i).Quantity -= _rndAmt;
}
```

Is this a statistically/mathematically proper way to handle this, or is there a distribution formula out there that handles this? The kicker is that while this pseudo code would run 200 times (so each bucket has a chance to alter its quantities) it would have to run X number of times depending on the TYPE of widget (which currently stands at just 11 flavors, but is expected to expand significantly in the future).

**{EDIT}**
This system is for a commodity trading game. Quantities at the 200 shops must differ because the inventory will determine the price at that station. The distro can't be even because that would make all prices the same. Over time, prices will naturally get out of balance, but the inventory must start out off-balance. And all inventories have to be at least similar in scope (ie, no one shop can have 1 item, and another have 900,000)

Comment: It's for a commodity trading game, and this is an initial seed method for distributing quantities of items to different shops in the game world. I don't want quantities to be equal because the quantity of the items in a shop determines the price; if all prices are the same, then there's no difference in buying/selling at one port over any other.

Comment: Put one item in the first bucket, two items in the second bucket and so on until the last bucket, into which you put all the remaining items. That fulfils your requirement...

Comment: I plan to have more targeted simulations going on in the background once the numbers are jumbled, in addition to player activity to ensure that players don't always have a single, static trading route that they bounce between to make wads of cash. I just need to get those numbers jumbled the first time to start things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there is a solution. You could use [Dirichlet Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) for such task. Property of the distribution is that

Sum<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub> = 1

So solution would be to sample 200 (equal the number of buckets) random values from Dirichlet, and then multiply each value by 950,000 (or whatever total inventory is) and that would give you number of items per bucket. If you want non-uniform sampling, you could tweak `alpha` in the Dirichlet sampling.

Items per bucket shall be rounded up/down, of course, but that is pretty trivial

I have Dirichlet sampling in C# somewhere, if you struggle to implement it - tell me and I would dig it out

UPDATE

I found some code, .NET Core 2, below is the excerpt. I used to sample Dirichlet RNs with the sample `alpha`s, making all of them different is trivial.

```
//
// Dirichlet sampling, using Gamma sampling from Math .NET
//

using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;
using MathNet.Numerics.Random;

static void SampleDirichlet(double alpha, double[] rn)
{
    if (rn == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("SampleDirichlet:: Results placeholder is null");

    if (alpha <= 0.0)
        throw new ArgumentException($"SampleDirichlet:: alpha {alpha} is non-positive");

    int n = rn.Length;
    if (n == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("SampleDirichlet:: Results placeholder is of zero size");

    var gamma = new Gamma(alpha, 1.0);

    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int k = 0; k != n; ++k) {
        double v = gamma.Sample();
        sum  += v;
        rn[k] = v;
    }

    if (sum <= 0.0)
        throw new ApplicationException($"SampleDirichlet:: sum {sum} is non-positive");

    // normalize
    sum = 1.0 / sum;
    for(int k = 0; k != n; ++k) {
        rn[k] *= sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I'm going to butcher this horribly, so apologies in advance... But using Dirichlet with the 200 buckets would produce a series of values between 0 and 1 (each representing a single bucket in the 200 bucket collection), and those values would represent a percent of the total 950,000 so that (roughly) the sum of the quantities in the 200 buckets is 950,000...?

Admittedly the info on Dirichlet I was able to find is significantly more math than I'm used to :D

Comment: @ChrisSmith  `using Dirichlet with the 200 buckets would produce a series of values between 0 and 1 (each representing a single bucket in the 200 bucket collection), and those values would represent a percent of the total 950,000 so that (roughly) the sum of the quantities in the 200 buckets is 950,000...?` Right, absolutely. And it is automatically summed properly.

Comment: Excellent! I'll give that a try. Thank you!